# Why doesn't Python have a "continue if" statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a pretty readable chunk of code I think,

```
for i in range(100):
    continue if i % 2 == 0
```

But it's not syntactically correct. We can do other nice things in Python like,

```
for i in things:
    total += 3 if i % 2 == 0 else 1
```

Or maybe,

```
return a if b > a else c
```

Why can't we do a `continue if` statement?

Comment: If you want to do that, use `if i % 2 == 0: continue`. It's one line, just the other way around and with a colon. I don't get why people always reject that. It's like they just hate colons.

Comment: If you want to do that, use `for i in range(1, 100, 2)` =)

Comment: `continue` is not particularly nice to begin with, in my opinion. I can’t recall a piece of code I liked better using `break` and `continue` compared to generator comprehensions, `all()`, `any()`; especially if we’re talking multiple breaks/continues in a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The flow:

```
for i in range(100):
    continue if i % 2 == 0
```

Would be equivalent to:

```
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
    ...
```

Or, more generically, to:

```
for i in range(100):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
```

Python language designers have a history of voting against changes to the grammar which are only offering slightly different ways of doing the same thing ("There should be one obvious way to do it").

The type of one-liner construct which you've mentioned

```
x if cond else y
```

was an exception made, here.  It was added to the language to offer a less error-prone way of achieving what many users were already *attempting* to achieve with `and` and `or` short-circuiting hacks ([source: Guido](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-September/056546.html)). 
 Code in the wild was using:

```
cond and x or y
```

Which is not logically equivalent, yet it's an easy mistake to make for users who were already familiar with the ternary `cond ? : x : y` syntax from C.  A correct equivalent is:

```
(cond and [x] or [y])[0]
```

But, that's ugly.  So, the rationale for the addition of an expression `x if cond else y` was stronger than a mere convenience.

Comment: Thank you. I had a feeling there was some Python lore in the background here :)

Answer (score 3):

Because `x if cond else y` is actually an **expression**. 
Expressions are statements which evaluate to a value, in this case, either `x` or `y`.

`continue` is not a value, so there's that. Also,

```
if cond:
    continue
```

is really not much harder or more "error prone" than `continue if cond`, whereas `v = x if cond else y` is probably better than

```
if cond:
    v = x
else:
    v = y
```

There's also the fact that if we allowed `continue if cond`, we add a new way to use this `_ if cond` pattern, i.e. we allow it without an `else`.

For more info:
https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-308.html

Comment: Thank you, I agree there is a ambiguity with what to do with the `else` in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Python does have such a thing, the syntax is just a bit different. Instead of the "if and "continue" being combined as one statement, they are separated into a conditional statement (if, while etc), and a control flow (continue, pass, break etc) if it evaluates to true. In your first code example, the syntax would be:

```
for i in range(100):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        continue
    else:
        #you could also add an else like this do something else if the 
        #number evaluated to odd
```

This will move on to the next iteration of the outer loop.There are also other helpful iteration tools like this, called "Control Flow Tools." I'll include a link to the Python docs that explain this. There's a ton of useful stuff there, so please do have a look.

Others here have also suggested a single-line syntax, which works too. It is, however, good to understand both approaches; this way you can keep your code as simple as possible, but you'll also have the ability to nest loops and conditions if your algorithm  will benefit from it.

Happy coding!

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Your explanation basically states that the `continue` keyword exists - that much is obvious! The question is asking why don't get the same syntactic sugar surrounding it as we do other keywords.

Comment: I don't agree that's what the question is asking. I took it to mean that he wonders why the continue and if aren't some amalgam. But of course absent of clarification from the asker, you and I could only argue semantics. If, however, the question were as you believe it to be, my answer would be that really all languages can accomplish the same tasks; the difference then, is in the steps that need to be taken to accomplish said task. At that point the point it becomes a matter of syntactical preference. Thus, if the question is as you state, it should be downvoted as subjective.